# CasperJS Button is clicked but doesnt redirect

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
  }
});
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;

casper.start("https://kit.kijiji.ca/Index.aspx");

casper.then(function() {
  this.sendKeys('input[name="login_username"]', 'example@example.com');
  this.sendKeys('input[name="login_password"]', 'password');
});

casper.thenClick('button', function() {
  this.echo("Button clicked.");
});

casper.wait(500, function() {
  casper.click(x("//input[@value='Login / Ouvrir une session']"));
});

casper.wait(1000, function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
  this.capture('example.png');
  casper.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

Hi there, I searched all around the web and couldn't find a solution to my problem so i decided to post here.

I'm trying to automatically log into this website and I successfully fill in the input fields and click the button but nothing happens when the credentials are correct.

Although when I enter in false credentials I can see from that from the casperjs capture that the button is being clicked since the page displays "invalid username / password".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB.I'm currently using the latest version of PhantomJS(2.1.1) and I did not get any errors from those events. Also now with the correct credentials the capture function returns an error of "Failed to save screenshot to example.png; please check permissions..."
This is what I got from the resource.error event
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 5,
    "errorString": "Operation canceled",
    "id": 78,
    "status": null,
    "statusText": null,
    "url": "https://kit.kijiji.ca/Index.aspx"
}

Comment: I don't think you're using PhantomJS 2.1.1. CasperJS includes an older version of PhantomJS if you installed it through NPM. Try running it as `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any script.js`

Comment: @ArtjomB. I installed PhantomJS manually. I've just figured out that it is logging in but for some reason when I try to capture it, it won't allow me. I'm able to download the source. The site is mostly Javascript, could I be doing something wrong in that matter?

Comment: I see no problem with your script. The "Failed to save screenshot to example.png; please check permissions..." error is probably due to a permission problem. You should check that you can write into the directory you're running this from.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The directory is public, I have no issue writing to it from any other website or from the same website used in my script when I'm not logging in. I think it may be the website, could it not be calling some JS files that need to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Your login portion is under a form with a post action. U can try to submit the form rather clicking on the login button. I also faced this problem and get solution by this way:

```
    this.fill('form#formname', {
        login_username: 'example@example.com',
        login_password: 'password',
    }, false);

    this.thenEvaluate(function () {
        document.querySelector('form#formname').submit();
    });
```

Hope you can solve the problem. Please put the form name properly.